# Trouble Naming Constants: Two Right-Angled Triangles

Tags: geometry, naming-conventions, constants, terminology

i'm trying to come up with appropriate constant names for two right-angled triangles that can be rotated.

[image]

the image above shows the two different versions of a right-angled triangle.  the right angle of the orange triangle is in the bottom-right while the right angle of the blue triangle is in the bottom-left.

from that, let's assume i will name each constant as:

```
public static const RIGHT_ANGLE_BOTTOM_RIGHT:String = "rightAngleBottomRight";
public static const RIGHT_ANGLE_BOTTOM_LEFT:String = "rightAngleBottomLeft";
```

besides those constant names being quite long and not very descriptive, these triangles can be rotated.  therefore, if the orange triangle (`RIGHT_ANGLE_BOTTOM_RIGHT`) is rotated -90º, its name is now misleading (and conflicting) since its right angle is now in the bottom left of the triangle shape.

so i'm searching for constant names for these rotatable, right-angled triangles which are clear and distinguishing (and ideally short).  currently, my "best" is simply calling them type 1 and type 2.  while those names are unmistakably distinguishing, it certainly isn't at all clear of their shape, especially since they can be rotated.

```
package
{
public final class TriangleStyle
    {
    public static const ISOSCELES:String = "isosceles";
    public static const RIGHT_Type1:String = "right1";
    public static const RIGHT_Type2:String = "right2";
    }
}
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Wouldn't LEFT (orange) and RIGHT (blue) be a good convention to adhere to?

Comment: i see where you are coming from, but naming them RIGHT_RIGHT and RIGHT_LEFT (or similar) would be really confusing.  more so than RIGHT_TYPE1 and RIGHT_TYPE2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `HOA` and `HAO` -- I'll leave the derivation to you -- and note that these names are invariant under rotation.